# Cannot import torch module

Tags: python, installation, pytorch

I cannot seem to properly install pytorch on my computer, so here is the background of what I have done:

I had already installed python on my computer and it worked. I used it in Eclipse, using pyDev, so I don't know if that could be the problem. Now I want to install pytorch, so I installed anaconda and entered the command for installing pytorch. To get the right command, I use https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, where I tried the options both with and without cuda. In both cases I get an error when I type "import torch".

I have also installed miniconda and tried the same with that without succes. I also tried to work in IDLE in stead of Eclipse, but I keep getting the "no module named 'torch'" error. Each time I run a command in anaconda it appears that the installation is succesfull, but I still can't import 'torch'.

Any idea what the problem could be or what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt or terminal and type:
pip3 install pytorch

If it says pip isn't installed then type: python -m pip install -U pip

Then retry importing Pytorch module

Answer (score 0):

Using anaconda, I think you can check to see if pytorch is properly installed inside your conda environment using `conda list` inside your environment. If it is shown in the list of installed packages, you can directly try to run `python` in command line and `import torch` as in the official Pytorch tutorial:

```
import pytorch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

For IDEs like Eclipse, you need to edit the settings of your project so that it uses the correct conda environment.

Comment: The conda prompt claims that it has been installed well, so I guess it must be a problem with the IDE? But shouldn't IDLE work without adjusting something? A friend of mine installed python (without installing Eclipse or PyDev) and said that IDLE could immediately import the torch module when he installed it with anadoconda. What kind of setting do I have to change?

Comment: When there are multiple environments inside your system (e.g. using Anaconda or Miniconda), each environment may contain different packages so there are no guarantees that the IDE can immediately use the 'correct' environment (with torch library). In your friend's case, I guess he may only have one environment inside his system. In the long-term, I don't think having only one environment would scale well. About the setting, it depends on the IDE that you are using, I think you can easily search for it. For example in Pycharm, I think you can choose the environment in Settings/Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create conda-env and reinstall pytorch on conda-env.
Then try to import torch again.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Comment: When you try import pytorch from  conda-prompt instread of Eclipse, so we can define what exactly the problem, IDE problem or Conda Library problem.